# unexpected result by cutting the last column with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

```
echo '60 test' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'
```

result:

> 60 test

the last column is not cut. but it works pretty well with

```
echo '60 home' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'
```

result:

> 60

why?

Comment: Try `\S+` instead of `[^\s]+`. Also there no need to group  and replace, just remove.

Comment: Try the following few others ;)  `echo '60 home' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'`  `echo '60 homes' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'`  `echo '60 test' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'` `echo '60 tett' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'`

Answer (score 5):

`[^\s]+` means `not backslash or s repeated 1 or more times` and `test` contains `s` while `home` does not and so the latter matches the regexp while the former doesn't.

You should have used either of these instead to match non-space:

```
$ echo '60 test' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+\S+$/\1/'
60

$ echo '60 test' | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^[:space:]]+$/\1/'
60
```

As @potong suggested in a comment, to remove the last column with sed all you really need is:

```
sed -E 's/\s+\S+$//'
```

I switched from `-r` to `-E` as `-r` is GNU sed only while `-E` is GNU or OSX/BSD sed so it's generally the better option to use BUT OSX/BSD sed won't recognize `\s` or `\S` so changing from `-r` to `-E` doesn't really make the script more portable in this case, you'd have to use this instead:

```
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+//'
```

and then to be completely portable to all POSIX seds it'd be:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}[^[:space:]]\{1,\}//'
```

or this would behave the same if there's always 2 or more fields:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*//'
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed -E 's/\s+\S+$//' file` is enough to remove the last column?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just printing the first part of your string before the space without doing any other modification, you can simply use `cut`

```
echo '60 test' | cut -d' ' -f1
60
```

where you define your delimiter (-d) and the field (-f) you want to select. 
No need to go for a complex solution using `sed` and doing some replacement operations.

With `awk` you can also print the first field:

```
echo '60 test' | awk '{print $1}'
60
```

or via `grep` in perl mode to have the `\s` taken into account

```
echo '60 test' | grep -oP '^.*?(?=\s)'
60
```